# A improper integral with series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, residue-calculus

Show that 
$$\begin{align}
  & \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{\cos \alpha x}{( \beta^2+x^2 )( ( \beta +1 )^2+x^2 )\cdots ( ( \beta +n )^2+x^2 )} \, \text{d}x = 2\pi \sum\limits_{k=0}^n ( -1 )^k \frac{( 2\beta -1+k )!}{( 2\beta +n+k )!} \frac{1}{k!( n-k )!}{\text{e}^{-\alpha (\beta +k)}} \\ 
 & n\in \mathbb{N},\ \ \alpha ,\ \beta >0 
\end{align}$$

Comment: When asking questions on this site it is customary to include your thoughts about the problem as well as what you have tried to do to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{(\beta^2+x^2)((\beta+1)^2+x^2 )\cdots((\beta+n)^2+x^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\mathrm{Re}\left(\int_{\gamma(R)}\frac{\exp(i\alpha z)}{(\beta^2+z^2)((\beta+1)^2+z^2 )\cdots((\beta+n)^2+z^2)}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma(R)$ is the contour from $-R$ to $+R$ and then circling counterclockwise along $|z|=R$ through the upper half plane.

The residue of the integrand at $z=i(\beta+k)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\exp(-\alpha(\beta+k))}{2i(\beta+k)}\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\ne k}}^n\frac1{(\beta+j)^2-(\beta+k)^2}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{\exp(-\alpha(\beta+k))}{2i(\beta+k)}\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\ne k}}^n\frac1{(2\beta+k+j)|j-k|}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{\exp(-\alpha(\beta+k))}{ik!(n-k)!}\prod_{j=0}^n\frac1{2\beta+k+j}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{\exp(-\alpha(\beta+k))}{ik!(n-k)!}\frac{\Gamma(2\beta+k)}{\Gamma(2\beta+k+n+1)}\\
\end{align}
$$
Summing the residues and multiplying by $2\pi i$ gives that the integral is
$$
2\pi\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{\exp(-\alpha(\beta+k))}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{\Gamma(2\beta+k)}{\Gamma(2\beta+k+n+1)}
$$
which, for integer $2\beta$, is what you have:
$$
2\pi\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{\exp(-\alpha(\beta+k))}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{(2\beta+k-1)!}{(2\beta+k+n)!}
$$